# Marklogic: how to pass integer to sem:sparql-triples in bindings

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I'd like to pass an integer to sem:sparql-triples to use as a LIMIT or as an OFFSET. I have passed other variables with the bindings map, but have struggled to get the query to accept an integer. Borrowing some code from ML's documentation to demonstrate:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
  at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $string := "
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jacqueline_Kennedy_Onassis>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eunice_Kennedy_Shriver> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_F._Kennedy,_Jr.>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jacqueline_Kennedy_Onassis> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rosemary_Kennedy>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jacqueline_Kennedy_Onassis> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Joseph_Patrick_Kennedy_Sr.>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rosemary_Kennedy> .
"

let $triples := sem:rdf-parse($string, "turtle")
let $bindings := map:map()
let $put := map:put($bindings,"limit",1)

return
sem:sparql-triples("
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE{ 
?s ?p ?o.
} 
ORDER BY ?o
LIMIT ?limit
", $triples, $bindings)
```

In QConsole this returns the error:

Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected variable, expecting integer literal

So, I tried a few things to add the value to my bindings map as an integer:

```
let $put := map:put($bindings,"limit",xs:integer(1))
```

and

```
let $put := map:put($bindings,"limit",sem:typed-literal('1',sem:iri("xs:integer")))
```

But so far I've been unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full error message is:

```
XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error,
unexpected <variable>, expecting <integer literal>
```

And it's at line 7, where the limit expression is. So I conclude that it isn't a matter of integer vs untyped. You simply can't use a variable there: it has to be a literal integer.

This seems to work, using 7.0-3:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" 
  at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $string := "
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jacqueline_Kennedy_Onassis>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eunice_Kennedy_Shriver> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_F._Kennedy,_Jr.>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows>
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jacqueline_Kennedy_Onassis> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rosemary_Kennedy>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jacqueline_Kennedy_Onassis> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Joseph_Patrick_Kennedy_Sr.>
<http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rosemary_Kennedy> .
"

let $triples := sem:rdf-parse($string, "turtle")
let $bindings := map:map()

return
sem:sparql-triples("
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE{ 
?s ?p ?o.
} 
ORDER BY ?o
LIMIT "||1,
$triples, $bindings)
```

Comment: It's not a MarkLogic issue, either, but from the SPARQL spec. If you put the query into the [sparql.org validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query), you'll get the syntax error: **Encountered "  "?limit "" at line 6, column 7.
Was expecting:
     ..."** (which doesn't say what it should be, but highlights what the problem is).  The corresponding production in the [SPARQL 1.1 grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#sparqlGrammar) is **[26] LimitClause ::= 'LIMIT' INTEGER**.

Comment: I guess that's it - I simply can't use a variable there. I just thought it might be a neat way of handling pagination within a SPARQL query. Thanks!

Comment: @rexsavior Well, `offset`, `limit`, and `order by` *are* how you should handle pagination in SPARQL (or else, retrieve a whole bunch of data and paginate it yourself).  You'll just need to interpolate the `limit` and `offset` values into the string;  they can't be SPARQL variables.

Comment: FYI MarkLogic 8 supports the use of externally bound variables in a limit or offset clause.

Answer (score 3):

I felt that an updated answer was required as in MarkLogic 8, your initial query will work - you can pass in a variable to set the limit.

(Caveat: only tested on 8.0-4.2)

Comment: I've confirmed that  the original query does work in MarkLogic 8.